# Is it possible to create a variable sized Hikari Connection Pool with 0 connections at start?

Tags: java, mysql, datasource, hikaricp

I have a distributed system that connects to around 150 different schemas/databases at the same time. For connecting to each schema/database, the application spins up a separate connection pool.
Application has varying usage, sometimes it needs active connections to only 10 schemas, sometimes it needs active connections for all.

In order to better manage resources, I want to have Hikari connection pool, which should have 0 connection by default, and then as the need grows, the connections should grow out to a specified threshold and then come back to 0.

My configurations are such:

```
hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(0);
hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(180000);
```

However, I see at least 1 active connection per pool in my MySQL database when I run sql

```
> show processList;
```

How do I ensure that when there is no need for the connection, the connection pool shrinks to 0?

Comment: Did you figure out how to shrink the pool to 0 connections?

Comment: Yes, I figured out that the above configuration is correct and it works. Just let the idletimeout pass.